# How to sort these using Javascript or Jquery Most effectively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to sort these using Javascript/JQuery Most effectively

```
<div>6</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>3</div>
```

Comment: Use the `sort()` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: I need to Make all these divs blue in the correct order

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/C2heg/ - maybe this will help

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment. Maybe you should show some code where you actually attempted something, had trouble, and came here for _assistance_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sort()` method to organise the `div` elements in to the required order, then `append()` them to the containing element in that order. Try this:

```js
$('div').sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).text() > $(b).text();
}).appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>6</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr=[];
var divs =  $("div");

$.each(divs,function(index){
    if($(divs[index]).html())
    arr.push($(divs[index]).html());
});

console.log(arr.sort());
```

Comment: How does this change the order of the elements in the DOM?